# Limits of logarithms with different bases.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, discrete-mathematics

Although this is a Discrete Structures problem, I am having trouble solving the pre-calculus portion of this problem.

The exercise gives us a $f(x)$ and a $g(x)$, and to figure out the asymptotic complexity. In this example, $f(x) = \log_{2}n^{3/2} $ and $g(x) = \log_{10}n $.

So I have a function: $ \log_{2}(n^{3/2})/\log_{10}n $

How do I find its limit as $n$ approaches infinity? I've simplified it to $ \log_{2}10\cdot\log_{2}n/2 $, but from what I understand from the answer, I'm supposed to have a constant, in other words $f(x) = \Theta (g(x))$.

How is $ \log_{2}(n{3/2}) /\log_{10}n $ a constant as $n$ approaches infinity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply basic logarithm rules:
$$\log_2(n^{3/2})=\frac 32\cdot\log_2(n)$$
and:
$$\log_{10}(n)=\frac{\log_2(n)}{\log_2(10)}$$
This gives us:
$$\frac{\log_2(n^{3/2})}{\log_{10}(n)}=\frac 32\cdot\log_2(10)$$

Answer (score 0):

Pull out the exponent 3/2 and retake the limit on the fraction. It becomes indeterminate but that can be dealt with through L'Hospital's Rule. If I am not mistaken, that fraction then becomes (ln10)/(ln2) when n→infinity